# Как сгенерировать java классы из документа schema.xsd

Tags: java, spring, xml, xsd, build-error

Вот  мой код

```
public class XsdExample {

public static void buildClasses(File xsdFile) throws IOException {
    SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
    sc.parseSchema(new InputSource(xsdFile.toURI().toString()));
    S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();

    JCodeModel cm = model.generateCode(null, null);
    cm.build(new File("."));
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File xsdFile = new File("example.xsd");
     buildClasses(xsdFile);

}
```

В папке testxsd находиться файл example.xsd, с помощью которого я хочу создать в этой же директории классы , которые описаны в файле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="example" type="example"/>

   <xs:complexType name="example">
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Ошибка возникает тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот собственно сама ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перепробовал много вариантов , но не получил никакого результата, если кто-то сталкивался с этой ошибкой помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: вставил ваш код и вашу схему....единственное что поправил - это вставил свои пути. как итог: https://i.imgur.com/RYufcwp.png

Comment: думал может в версии JVM проблема...воткнул 8-ую..все тоже генерируется нормально

Comment: попатайтесь почистить и пересобрать проект `mvn clean install` и после запустить снова

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с путями, ну и немного поправил код и теперь все работает как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]